# How do I take a 2D point, and project it into a 3D Vector by a perspective camera

Tags: math, 3d, 2d, projection

I have a 2D Point (x,y) and I want to project it to a Vector, so that I can perform a ray-trace to check if the user clicked on a 3D Object, I have written all the other code, Except when I got back to my function to get the Vector from the xy cords of the mouse, I was not accounting for Field-Of-View, and I don't want to guess what the factor would be, as 'voodoo' fixes are not a good idea for a library. any math-magicians wanna help? :-).

Heres my current code, that needs FOV of the camera applied:

```
sf::Vector3<float> Camera::Get3DVector(int Posx, int Posy, sf::Vector2<int> ScreenSize){
    //not using a "wide lens", and will maintain the aspect ratio of the viewport
    int window_x = Posx - ScreenSize.x/2;
    int window_y = (ScreenSize.y - Posy) - ScreenSize.y/2;
    float Ray_x = float(window_x)/float(ScreenSize.x/2);
    float Ray_y = float(window_y)/float(ScreenSize.y/2);

    sf::Vector3<float> Vector(Ray_x,Ray_y, -_zNear);
    // to global cords
    return MultiplyByMatrix((Vector/LengthOfVector(Vector)), _XMatrix, _YMatrix, _ZMatrix);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not too fart off, one thing is to make sure your mouse is in -1 to 1 space (not 0 to 1)
Then you create 2 vectors:

```
Vector3 orig = Vector3(mouse.X,mouse.Y,0.0f);
Vector3 far = Vector3(mouse.X,mouse.Y,1.0f);
```

You also need to use the inverse of your perspective tranform (or viewprojection if you want world space)

```
Matrix ivp = Matrix::Invert(Projection)
```

Then you do:

```
Vector3 rayorigin = Vector3::TransformCoordinate(orig,ivp);
Vector3 rayfar = Vector3::TransformCoordinate(far,ivp);
```

If you want a ray, you also need direction, which is simply:

```
Vector3 raydir = Normalize(rayfar-rayorigin);
```

Comment: You are using a 4x4 matrix for the projection, I assume? and I am unfamiliar with Vector3::TransformCoordinate, is that a function for multiplying a vector to a 4x4? how do I obtain the projection matrix from my camer's current matrix, and a FOV, zNear, zFar planes, and aspect ratio of one? am open to using OpenGL

Comment: Yes using 4x4 matrix for projection. TransformCoordinate tranforms a position (so technically it transforms as vector4 with last component set to 1), and get rid of the w after. To get projection Matrix (GL friendly, https://github.com/cinder/Cinder/blob/master/include/cinder/Matrix44.h or http://nopper.tv/glus.html , dx version : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb281727(v=vs.85).aspx) . Best is to keep your camera (view) as separate, then create projection from fov/near/far and multiply both matrices (since you often need them separate for other tasks).